How do I make Gnome position windows adjacent to each other, not overlapping (when there's space on the screen)?
Could someone help me figure out why Gnome window placement may have changed when i recently updated Ubuntu?  I already had installed Ubuntu 24.04 and about three weeks ago i merely updated it.
Before the update:
As shown in the first of the next two screenshots, when i open three Gedit windows they were positioned next to each other so they occupy the entire screen area. 
As shown in the second figure, when i first open a Gedit window and then open Firefox, they were placed next to each other so they occupy the entire screen. 
Not so now. The first window opens (as usual) on the left end of the screen. Subsequent windows open near it (with a gap of about one centimeter on the left between the left edge of the last open window).
I have the following settings:
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter center-new-windows false
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling false
I experimented with a few other options using gsettings.
None helped.
Thank you.
